# ASP.Net MVC Custom Authorization Policy Provider in razor view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, asp.net-authorization

For some application I need a custom Authorization Policy provider and followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and was able to successfully create one that works in the controller. Now when it comes to the view, in role-based authorization you can simply use the term `@if (User.IsInRole("SomeRole"))` to display or hide divs and resources.

How can I use a custom Authorization Policy provider in the view to determine if a given user could see stuff based on the evaluation of the policy?

I searched the web and couldn't find helpful information about it and also tried playing round with

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "PolicyName")).Succeeded)
```

But this wasn't successful either - it's not a policy either.

Has anyone done this before?

## Update

I am using the custom policy provider in the controller as follows:

```
[MinimumAgeAuthorize(15)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
       //some code
}
```

I cannot do

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "MinimumAgeAuthorize(15)")).Succeeded)
```

What is the equivalent for it in the razor view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what didn't work for you, but this is how you can use the AuthorizationService.

For this example let's assume that you defined a policy in startup:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // assume that claimtype of role is role.
    options.AddPolicy("MyRolePolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("role", "SomeRole"));
});
```

This means that code restricted with 'MyRolePolicy' is only accessable when the user has the role 'SomeRole'. The equivalent of `User.IsInRole("SomeRole")`.

In the view inject the service and test the policy for the user:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService _authorizationService

@if ((await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "MyRolePolicy")).Succeeded)
{
}
```

When you use Custom Authorization Policy Providers, the policies are added through middleware, e.g.:

```
public class AuthorizationPolicyProvider : DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    public AuthorizationPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public async override Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        // check static policies first
        var policy = await base.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);

        if (policy == null)
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddRequirements(new PermissionRequirement(policyName)).Build();

        return policy;
    }
}
```

In this example the policies are added (if not exists) as permission where claimtype is `permission` and value is policyname. When I add the policy `MyPermission` it will check for a claimtype `permission` with value `MyPermission`.

In the view:

```
@if ((await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "MyPermission")).Succeeded)
{
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'it's not a policy either', but the Authorization Policy Provider returns policies. So you should be able to validate these policies. Whether it's a simple claimtype (e.g. permission or role) or a more complex policiy with parameters. But the name must match. Also make sure that you inject the necessary handlers, services, etc.

## Update

You can also validate using requirements:

```
@if ((await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, null, new MinimumAgeRequirement(15))).Succeeded)
```

Where MinimumAgeRequirement is the requirement itself.

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationservice):

```
AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal, Object, IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement>)
```

> Checks if a user meets a specific set of requirements for the
> specified resource

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Still I'm not quite sure if this is what I am looking for. In the controller I use my custom policy provider like this: `[MinimumAgeAuthorize(15)]` (Not `[Authorize("SomePolicy")]` or `[Authorize(Role = "SomeRole")]`). How would this translate into the razor view? I cannot do `@if ((await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "MinimumAgeAuthorize(15)")).Succeeded)` - See also my updated question